# How to extract C code portion using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Hope you all are doing well. I need a simple solution to my problem. I want to write a python code which takes C code as a string. Then regex like this `r"#([^}]+)>|#([^}]+)\.h"` will detect the headers files part (From # include to '>' or '.h'). I also wanted to extract both group1 and group2 regex part. Then python code will extract and remove that header part of the C code and save it in 'any' variable. Then I want remaining code to be extracted as any other variable.

For example str1=

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include conio.h`
```

and str2=

```
void main (void)
{
int b = 32;
int a=34;
int wao= 35;
}
```

The input source code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include conio.h

void main (void)
{
int b = 32;
int a=34;
int wao= 35;
}
```

Comment: Don't parse a language like C with a regex.  It's too complex for a regex to handle.

Comment: I know it's complex to handle but I really needed that for my project.

Comment: If u know any other method then kindly let me know so that I can transform it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all all `include` in C are going to be in a single line (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354443/include-multiple-header-files-at-once-with-only-one-include-expression)) so you can instead use `#(.*)` (I've found it works better for this) and validate later. if you use the regex that you have in the post you are going to have trouble in the next step (try it your self)

if `src_code` is your input source code then

```
headers = list(re.finditer(r"#(.*)", src_code)) # Extract all the header matches
```

as a result

```
[<re.Match object; span=(1, 20), match='#include <iostream>'>,
 <re.Match object; span=(21, 38), match='#include <string>'>,
 <re.Match object; span=(39, 55), match='#include conio.h'>]
```

You can now get all the header strings in a list ( which you may verify if are valid if you want)

```
headers = [i.group() for i in headers] # get the match from above
```

And you can remove all the `#include` from the source code using `re.sub`

```
src_code = re.sub("#(.*)(\n+)", "", src_code) # Also remove any `\n` coming after
```

And there you have it

- `src_code`

```c
void main (void)
{
int b = 32;
int a=34;
int wao= 35;
}
```

- for `headers` you can use `"\n".join(headers)` but note that they may be declared inside scopes aka brackets `{}` (functions, structs or raw etc)

```py
['#include <iostream>', '#include <string>', '#include conio.h']
```